# How to show the record count together with response data in django-restframework

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a requirement to show the total record count together with response data in *django-restframework*. I manage to add the status, but not the total record count as below:

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": [
    {
      ...
    },
    {
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

The expected result should be

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": [
    {
      ...
    },
    {
      ...
    }
   ]
}
```

#### File *views.py*

```py
class MyView(APIView):
    serializer_class = MySerializers

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        rs = MyModel.objects.filter(segment_column_name='SEGMENT1')
        serializer = MySerializers(rs, many=True)
        return Response({"status": "success", "data": serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do as follows:

```py
def get(self, request, format=None):
    rs = MyModel.objects.filter(segment_column_name='SEGMENT1')
    serializer = MySerializers(rs, many=True)
    return Response({"status": "success", "data": serializer.data, "count": len(rs)}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

FYI: You can also use [count()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#count) to count the items of your queryset, but in your case len() will be faster

Comment: your answer is correct.